# YouTube API v3 nodejs quickstart not working

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs?hl=en_US

after running the code I get the url below:

```
Authorize this app by visiting this url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access...
Enter the code from that page here:
```

But after signing in I was brought to this link with no code.

http://localhost/?code=4/0ARtbsJoy4Qoio0JdBeaPpTAnuvJn9gKarNnLzF3cpK_RQ7DgP_oO-Q1QPpfOS5OO6JYgWw&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the code you have to provide is just:

```
4/0ARtbsJoy4Qoio0JdBeaPpTAnuvJn9gKarNnLzF3cpK_RQ7DgP_oO-Q1QPpfOS5OO6JYgWw
```

(deduced from the URL you provided).

Comment: ohh... I see.... It's ok I found a workaround to do what I wanted using just the googleapis package from npm